# Microsoft Feedback Client issues with uploads

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, user-feedback

We're having some serious issues with the mfbclient.exe tool that is part of the feedback platform of VSTS. Basically, our stakeholder's uploads are not being sent.

This is extremely frustrating as you can imagine, as the ability to take screenshots etc is a major benefit of using the tool.

Members of the development team who have VS2017 installed on their machines as well as the feedback tool, can access the feedback request via the email that is automatically sent out when you click on "Request Feedback". Everything works perfectly.

If we send the request to a stakeholder, they can click on the link and it opens up the tool correctly, they can step through the items and make notes etc., and when they submit, their responses come through into VSTS. However, none of their attachments come through. They all say '(Uploading) filename.png' in VSTS.

Upon looking at one of the stakeholder's machines, I can see the mfbclient.exe tray icon says '0MB of 10MB transferred'. Restarting the machine doesn't change this - the attachments don't get uploaded.

Upon further investigation, under `%localappdata%\microsoft\team foundation\x.0\testmanagement\` i can see an XML file which contains the list of all the screenshots / attachments etc that are to be loaded. The screenshot files themselves also exist (so, the files aren't missing/deleted). For some reason, the files just aren't uploading.

If I remove the XML file, it clears the attachment 'queue', but as soon as more feedback is entered and a screenshot added, the same issue occurs.

I noticed there was an mfbclient.exe.config file, which I edited on one of the stakeholder's machines and changed the trace level to '4' (verbose), which I thought would shed some light on the issue. However, I can't see anywhere that the logs might be. Does anyone know?

I have tested this with the stakeholder being part of the exact same security group as myself and the team (as I thought perhaps it was a permissions error), but this doesn't change the behaviour.

The only real differences I can think of between myself and team, and the people who are having the issues (and there are quite a few users who have the same issue so it's not just 1 person's problem), is that these people are stakeholders rather than subscribers (shouldn't make a difference), and they don't have Visual Studio installed on their machines (also, shouldn't make a difference).

Can anyone please shed any light on this issue? Has anyone else had the problem? Can someone from MSFT help?

Comment: Tested on my side, everything works as expected even no Visual Studio installed (only installed the Team explorer and Feedback client). So, please try to install the [standalone Team explorer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/04/05/team-explorer-for-tfs-2017/) if they don't have Visual Studio installed on their machines, then try it again.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT can you comment on Sebastian's answer below?

Comment: Yes, checked that again,Sebastian is right. See my comments below. So the solution is changing the access level to basic. You could accept it as an answer.

Comment: Issue is reported here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/203718/feeback-client-upload-fails-for-stakeholder.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem with our VSTS.
The problem really is because of the Stakeholder-License.

If I submit a feeback with a stakeholder account the upload stays at 0%. When I change the user then to Basic in VSTS, the upload starts automatically and completes.

EDIT: this issue has been fixed, as per this forum post: [Feedback Client - Upload fails for Stakeholder](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/203718/feeback-client-upload-fails-for-stakeholder.html)

Comment: Yes, it's related to the access levels.  **Basic** provides access to most features, except for Test and other premium features. **Stakeholder** access to those users who need to enter bugs, view backlogs, boards, charts, and dashboards, but who don't have a TFS CAL.  See  [About access levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/access-levels) for details.

Comment: Thanks for feedback? Has this changed since 2015?
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/6760073-allow-vso-stakeholder-license-to-use-feedback-clie

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT that seems wrong to me. Stakeholders can enter bugs etc, yes, but what you're saying is although they can do this, they can't attach pictures?? Is this considered a 'premium feature'?

Answer (score 2):

Just as Sebastian mentioned, the solution is changing the Access Level from **Stakeholder**  to **Basic**.

> **Basic** provides access to most features, except for Test and other premium features. **Stakeholder** access to those users who need to
>   enter bugs, view backlogs, boards, charts, and dashboards, but who
>   don't have a TFS CAL. See [About access levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/access-levels) for details.

**Basic** provides most features, Stakeholders can use the Feedback Client since TFS 2013 Update#5 based on [this user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/6760073-allow-vso-stakeholder-license-to-use-feedback-clie). Can't attach pictures seems a permission limitation for Stakeholders.

Whatever seems it's **by design** or a feature missed or **an issue** on current version of TFS and VSTS based on the Stakeholders license limitation. However the requirement make sense and I have submitted a new [**user voice here**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33487726-allow-vso-stakeholder-to-attach-pictures-using-fee) to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve that in future.

---

**UPDATE**:

I agree with your point of view, it's more inclined to be a bug. And you have submittetd a feedback here:  [Feeback Client - Upload fails for Stakeholder](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/203718/feeback-client-upload-fails-for-stakeholder.html)

Whether user voice or bug, development team will take care of them. So, let's wait for the response. And for now, you can change to the **Basic Level** to upload the pictures.

Comment: With all due respect, I don't think we should have to 'request' this as a feature, I think it's a feature that is lacking and should be there. It's an error that it's been omitted..

Comment: @benpage Yeah, I agree with your point of view, it's more inclined to be a bug. I have updated the answer, just check that.